# How to play YouTube videos without silence at start/end in a playlist?

Tags: youtube

I have some videos in a music playlist whose playtime is longer then the length of the sound. Usually it's several seconds at the end where it's just silence.

Is there anyway to fix this? The videos are not mine.

Comment: "The videos are not mine" - you need to be at least in the position to be able to edit the video. AFAIK you can't simply change the play back of the video without changing the underlying video file. The owner of the video on YouTube can crop the video online using the built-in editor. Otherwise you would need to download it and use some video editing software to crop the video file.

Comment: Please note that editing the video itself is not required but only playing a portion of it in a playlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature available in YouTube, nor have I ever heard of a addon for this. You could go out of your way and download the videos though and edit them yourself. If the video's liscense is under creative commons you can upload it to your own channel and then use the [YouTube Video Editor](http://www.youtube.com/editor)